# Datepicker - Year Only

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I am modifying a simple datepicker.

I would like to only have the **Year** dropdown (Month is not required).

[image]

I have tried to remove the Month dropdown by adding the css:

```
select.custom-select {
    display: none;
}
```

Unfortunately this not only removes the Month dropdown but the Year also, see below:
[image]

Please see **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-year-datepicker-ng-bootstrap)**

Comment: Just make your own select with some years on it

Comment: you could do `select.custom-select:nth-child(1)` but this really feels like using a plane to get to the shops. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution will be to use css to hide the first select element inside `ngb-datepicker-navigation-select` using `display:none`

Working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-year-datepicker-ng-bootstrap-8ag1xe

Answer (score 2):

You can add style to the first select

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-basic',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-basic.html',
  styles:[':host ::ng-deep select:first-child{display:none;}']
})
export class NgbdDatepickerBasic {
...
}
```

Reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-year-datepicker-ng-bootstrap-kyjfjz

Comment: `::ng-deep` is easily avoidable - use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and to stop the css leaking wrap the template in a unique class.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to use will be Datepicker from ngx-bootstrap.

Check out this link:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#min-mode

It has an option for display mode called min-mode, so you can't go beyond that.You can set min-mode to "year" in your case. Works beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

You can use yyyy formate to only a year.Try below code.

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yyyy',
    startingDay: 1,
    minMode: 'year'
};
```

Working Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/0SPMYQ6ND7AOfZwDAFB8?p=preview